# ExpressJS req.body is empty JSON

Tags: node.js, express

When I hit my POST endpoint with JSON using Postman, my expressJS application wrongly claims that my JSON is an empty object.

**Versions:**

express: "4.17.1"
npm: '7.11.1'
node: '15.12.0'

**Code:**

index.js

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const app = express();
const controller = require ( './modules/controller' );
app.use( express.json() );
app.post( '/broken', ( req, res ) => controller.post( req, res ) );
```

controller.js

```
module.exports.post = async ( req, res ) =>
{
    const body = req.body;
    log.debug( `body received from request ${JSON.stringify( body )}` );
}
```

Postman config:

POST body (raw):

```
{
    "a":"b"
}
```

Headers:

Content-Type: application/json

**Expected behaviour:**

Logs out: `body received from request {"a"="b"}`

**Actual behaviour:**

Logs out: `body received from request {}`

Comment: Does `req` have any non-null properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41WzB.png)

Just wanna point out that the issue may come from Postman. When you create a new call on Postman the default body (raw) type it uses is "text". It needs to be set to JSON instead.

Comment: Accepting this answer with extra details - Although raw JSON was selected already, Postman was mangling the request and sending the data as a Buffer array instead of JSON. I was able to narrow this down by exporting the request to `curl` and inspecting the output. Trashing the Postman query and creating a new one solved the issue.